# Inverting n-dimensional vector function

Tags: linear-algebra

As part of a differential geometry problem, I need to inverse this function to get $\vec{u}$ as a function of $\vec{x}$:

$$
\vec{x} = \left(\frac{2\vec{u}}{1 + |\vec{u}|^2}, \frac{1 - |\vec{u}|^2}{1 + |\vec{u}|^2} \right)
$$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried writing $\vec{x}$ as $(\vec{x_0}, x_n)$ so I have the relations $\vec{x_0} = \frac{2\vec{u}}{1 + |\vec{u}|^2}$ and $x_n = \frac{1 - |\vec{u}|^2}{1 + |\vec{u}|^2}$ but I'm not sure how to combine these in the right way, and also not quite sure how to handle the inverse when the magnitude is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that you are not going to get a global inverse, otherwise $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ would be diffeomorphic. So your function maps $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In fact, it is easy to see that $|\vec{x}|=1$.

Assume $x_n\neq -1$ (otherwise you need to rename your coordinate $x_n$). Then, from the definition of $x_n$ it is straightforward to obtain:
$$
|\vec{u}|^2=\frac{1-x_n}{1+x_n}
$$
whereas for $i=0\dots n-1$,
$$
u_i=\frac{1-|\vec{u}|^2}{2}\frac{x_i}{x_n}=\frac{x_i}{1+x_n}
$$